# how to do column-level locking? Is that possible?

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Let's say I have a table as below:

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | NAME | STATUS |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ADAM | ACTIVE |
|  2 | EVE  | ACTIVE |
|  3 | JOHN | ACTIVE |
+----+------+--------+
```

Let's say I want to do column-level locking - the transaction abort if other transaction modify the value of the same column, e.g

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | NAME | STATUS |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ADAM | ACTIVE | <- OK: Tx1: change NAME to ACE, Tx2: change STATUS to INACTIVE
|  2 | EVE  | ACTIVE | <- Abort: Tx1: change NAME to CAROL, Tx2: change NAME to CAT
|  3 | JOHN | ACTIVE | <- OK, same value: Tx1: change NAME to JAN, Tx2: change NAME to JAN
+----+------+--------+
```

What lock or isolation level I need to set?

Comment: You can only do row level locking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't lock individual column values natively.  You could make multiple tables with a one to one relationship; or you could roll your own optimistic locking:

```
select name from t where id=2; -- get Eve
update t set name='Carol' where id=2 and name='Eve' returning id;
-- if no rows updated, rollback and throw an error.
```

This would not consider it an error if other session(s) changed the value from Eve to Cat then back to Eve again in between the first two lines shown.

Comment: Are these two separate transactions or wrapped. in one transaction?